# In Spring, does @Controller accept requests only after completing any other beans' @PostConstruct methods?

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, postconstruct

I have to initialize something with DAO using @PostConstruct.

And before completing it, @Controller SHOULD NOT accept any request.

Is it default behaviour? Or need any other configuration?

Comment: Are you loading your DAO Bean lazily i.e using  @Lazy(true)?

Comment: @harrybvp No, there's no lazy loaded bean.